# Cross-compile for Windows under Ubuntu with Cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake, cross-compiling, libusb, mingw32

I'm trying to compile xc3sprog [xc3sprog](http://xc3sprog.sourceforge.net/) for Windows under Ubuntu 16.04. According to its README I do:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Toolchain-mingw32.cmake ..
```

In a result I have [cmake_output](http://pastebin.com/duHWr3JE).

I've installed libftdi with:

```
sudo apt install libftdi*
```

Could you help me?

## EDIT:

As stated in comments, now I have a problem with `#include <libusb/usb.h>`  which can't be found when `make` is eecuted. Where does it look for this file? In Linux host system headers or in mingw32 toolchain headers?
For me it seems that in toolchain, because when compiling Linux version there wasn't such an error (the different thing is that I can't find this libusb/usb.h file anywhere in system files, so I don't know how it work for Linux compilation...).

Comment: The Windows version of libftdi is needed. You can also try building everything (including libftdi) with MXE.

Comment: @Velkan: I've downloaded libftdi from https://sourceforge.net/projects/picusb/files/ and libftd2xx (Win x64) from http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm
Then I did:
`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Toolchain-mingw32.cmake -DLIBFTDI_LIBRARIES=/home/ds/libftdi_win_library/lib/libftdi1.dll.a -DLIBFTDI_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/ds/libftdi_win_library/include/libftdi1/ -DLIBFTD2XX_LIBRARIES=/home/ds/ftdi_win_library/Static/amd64/ftd2xx.lib -DLIBFTD2XX_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/ds/ftdi_win_library/ ..`

Cmake output: http://pastebin.com/dN9nQAA0
make output: http://pastebin.com/GWV6k9LA

Comment: Looks like `libusb` should be installed also.

Comment: Yep. Required header is in downloaded libftdi folder, but I have no idea how to point Cmake to it. For libftdi it was explicitely saying that something is required (e.g. LIBFTDI_LIBRARIES).